# ParseFacebookUtil: Apple Mach-O Linker, undefined symbol for architecture x86_64 PFDateFormatter

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

Error occurs after adding the ParseFacebookUtil 
**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFDateFormatter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**FRAMEWORKS**
[image]
I am using XCode 6.2

Thanks

edit:
I've added the frameworks social, and accounts. Same error still occurs.

Comment: I am having the same issues.  Did you ever get this fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this issue by deleting the Parse and Bolts framework, and re adding it back into the project.

Edit:
The best solution to this issue is by using cocoapods. It handles the dependencies better than manually dragging in the framework files.